# Refresh value react not value after action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

I'm in the React work by 2 hours and I have a problem with how the writer separate correctly the component, an example I have these windows

[image]

When I click the button "Set" I change the value `this.state.nameFramework`, If I write all code inside the App component my helloApp work but if I write the code in the separate component it not work in the instant time but for change the value of the variable this.state.nameframework I had reloaded the page.

My code

```
require('normalize.css/normalize.css');
require('styles/App.css');

import React from 'react';
import InputFramework from 'components/InputFramework';
import ListPerson from 'components/ListPerson';

const list = [
  {
    objectID: 1,
    'name': 'Vincenzo',
    'surname': 'Palazzo'
  },
  {
    objectID: 2,
    'name': 'Sara',
    'surname': 'Durante'
  }
];

let name = 'Vincent';
let nameFramework = 'React';

class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list,
      name,
      nameFramework
    };

    this.onSelectPerson = this.onSelectPerson.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitText = this.onSubmitText.bind(this);
    this.onChangeNameFramework = this.onChangeNameFramework.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmitText(){
    this.setState({nameFramework: this.state.nameFramework});
  }

  onChangeNameFramework(name){
    this.state.nameFramework = name;
  }

  onSelectPerson(name) {
    this.setState({name: name});
  }

  render() {
    //This is no good for my programmer style, resolve it please
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <InputFramework
                  name={this.state.name}
                  nameFramework={this.state.nameFramework}
                  onChange={this.onChangeNameFramework}
                  onClick={this.onSubmitText}
        />
        <ListPerson
          onClick={this.onSelectPerson}
        list={this.state.list}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default AppComponent;
```

Input component

```
    require('normalize.css/normalize.css');
    require('styles/App.css');

    import React from 'react';


    class InputFramework extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        //This is no good for my programmer style, resolve it please
        //The nameFramework not update
        let {onChange, onClick, name} = this.props;
        return (
          <div className='index'>
            <h1>Hello my name is {name} and I'm learning {this.props.nameFramework}</h1>
            <from>
              <input type='text'
                     onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}/>
              <button type='submit' onClick={() => onClick}>Set</button>
            </from>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    InputFramework.defaultProps = {};

    export default InputFramework;
```

List component

```
require('normalize.css/normalize.css');
require('styles/App.css');

import React from 'react';

class ListPerson extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    //This is no good for my programmer style, resolve it please
    const {onClick, list} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <ul>
          {list.map(function(item){
            return (
              <li key={item.objectID}>
                {item.name}
                <button type='button' onClick={() => onClick(item.name)}>Select</button>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ListPerson.defaultProps = {
};

export default ListPerson;
```

I this is a problem to how to write the code, now I ask you that you have more experience than me, can you help me to undestend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change (mutate) state directly in onChangeNameFramework handler.

Mutating state directly can lead to bugs.

State must be changed only by this.setState, so it must be like this:

```
  onChangeNameFramework(name){
    this.setState({
      nameFramework: name
    })
  }
```

Here is the docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Another problem is in InputFramework component, when you submit a form the page reloads, to prevent it, you should add e.preventDefault() like this:

```
class InputFramework extends React.Component {

  render() {
    //This is no good for my programmer style, resolve it please
    //The nameFramework not update
    let {onChange, onClick, name} = this.props;

    const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        onClick();
    }

    return (
      <div className='index'>
        <h1>Hello my name is {name} and I'm learning {this.props.nameFramework}</h1>
        <form>
          <input type='text'
                 onChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}/>
          <button type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>Set</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly in AppComponent the following code is redundant, since you are setting the same state:

```
  onSubmitText(){
       this.setState({nameFramework: this.state.nameFramework});
  }
```

You already handle the change of framework name in onChangeNameFramework handler.

I think using both onSubmitText and onChangeNameFramework handler seems unnecesary here, only one of them will be enough.

Playground:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-frost-qutb0

Comment: I'm using the function **onSubmitText** because I want change the value when I submit the button, exists another mode for get the value from input?

Comment: You are already getting the changed framework name through onChangeNameFramework, so setting it from onSubmitText has no effect in this case.

Comment: Yes, but if I want change the name framework when I click on the button and not when I change the value on the input text?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo  then you can do like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-johnson-j2xvl

Comment: Thanks so much :) another question, why inside the event `handleClick` of the component `InputFramework` you have inserted the `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Because without it the page refreshes which we don't want